# How do I know if I am using the correct drivers for my video card?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, video, graphics-card

'Correct' in this context meaning 'most recent stable version'

I'm having issues whereby the screen isn't redrawing itself properly and sometimes I have to mouseover things in order for it to redraw them.

WinXP SP3

Answer (score 4):

Go to the manufacturer's website for your video card and see what the latest driver version is. If it's beta (test release) it should say so right in the download links, if not the release notes.

You can also look to see if there are additional drivers for your monitor at that manufacturer but I rarely install those.

Check that your driver notes say the latest version is for Windows XP.

Comment: Lol, I used the built in Device Manager 'update' facility in WinXP and it totally broke my machine. BSODing on boot. Had to open with a previous 'system restore point' to get it back. Thanks NVidia!!